# How do I parse "invoice" level data into columnar data for analysis?

Tags: python, r, parsing

Data looks like this

**Invoice 1**

```
ID
Lat
Long
Year 
Month
Observations
1
.
.
.
n
```

#-----

**Invoice 2-n** (pattern repeats)

My goal is to end up with a table in the form

```
ID | Lat | Long | Year | Month | Obs 1 | Obs 2 | Obs 3 | Obs n
```

`#-----` acts as the delimiter between invoices

It's easy to go from wide to long at that point, but what's the best way to write the mapping rule and iterate through the data? All my data is in a single .csv, but it's over 1 million lines.

I'm looking for a place to start, and a general process for handling data in this format.

Comment: Is `n` known and fixed?

Comment: @DYZ `n` is known but variable based on the invoice. I.E. Invoice 1 might have 38 obs (n=38) and Invoice 4 might have 90.

Comment: How do you know when the next invoice begins?

Comment: @DYZ Currently there's a text delimiter between each one `#-----` Each invoice also begins with a unique ID number.

Comment: Please include the information about the delimiter in your question, because it is essential. As for the ID number, you cannot tell whether the number is `Obs n` or the next ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    invoice = []
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("Invoice"):
            outfile.writerow(invoice)
            invoice = []
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue
        invoice.append(line)
    outfile.writerow(invoice)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop should work:

```
with open('...') as infile:
  data = []
  line = []
  item = infile.readline().strip()
  while item != '':
    if item.startswith('#-----'):
      data.append(line)
      line = []
    else:
      line.append(item)
    item = infile.readline().strip()
```

At the end, `data` is a list of lists (not necessarily rectangular).